# i am creating a kernel module to find the resident pages for all the process

Tags: linux, process, linux-kernel

I am creating a kernel module to find the resident pages for all the process. I am using `get_mm_rss()` and for_each_process but it works 
only for init process / first time after first iteration it doesn't    work.

```
int __init schedp(void){
    struct task_struct *p;

    for_each_process(p) {
        int pid = task_pid_nr(p);
        printk("Process: %s (pid = %d) , (rpages : %lu)\n", 
                p->comm, pid, get_mm_rss(p->mm)); 
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Results:

```
BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 00000160,
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting `NULL` in `p->mm`, because some tasks may have invalid `mm` pointer because they are exiting or don't have `mm` (because they are kernel-threads, not sure).

When you confused on how to use kernel API, always look for examples inside kernel itself. Quick search with cross-reference tool gave me [kernel/cpu.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/cpu.c#L271):

```
for_each_process(p) {
    struct task_struct *t;

    /*
     * Main thread might exit, but other threads may still have
     * a valid mm. Find one.
     */
    t = find_lock_task_mm(p);
    if (!t)
        continue;
    cpumask_clear_cpu(cpu, mm_cpumask(t->mm));
    task_unlock(t);
}
```

Note that you need to call `find_lock_task_mm()` and `task_unlock()` and explicitly check for `NULL`.

Comment: thanks,i used all the above code, but the problem is still remains the same ... plz can u solve this for me

Answer (score 0):

*finally it works after creating a function which checks a mm_struct  is valid or not for_each_process*

```
struct task_struct *task_mm(struct task_struct *p){
struct task_struct *t;
rcu_read_lock();
for_each_thread(p, t) {
task_lock(t);
if (likely(t->mm))
goto found;
task_unlock(t);
}
t = NULL;
found:
rcu_read_unlock();
return t;
}
```